# They're closing their shop

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

We were shopping at the mall.

It's late and all the shops were starting to close.

> "They're closing."
>
> "They're closing their shop."

Will the second sentence mean the shop is bankrupt?

Comment: That's not how I would interpret the second sentence – not if it's the end of the day and everyone else is closing their doors, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They're closing

In this sentence **closing** does not have an object (it's intransitive), and for [this meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/close) "They" can only apply to the shop, not the staff.

> They're closing their shop

In this sentence, "They" could refer to the the owners (which might imply that the shop was closing permanently) or to the staff (which would mean that right now the staff are outside the shop and locking the doors). If the owners also work in the shop, if could mean either.

Either sentence could mean that the shop is closing at the end of the day, or that it is closing permanently. Unless the context indicates otherwise, I would assume that the shop was closing at the end of the day, especially if it was late in the day and other shops are closing too.

To indicate that the shop was closing permanently, you could use one of these expressions.

> The shop is **closing its doors**
>   The shop is **closing down**
>   They are **closing down**

**[shut up shop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shut-up-shop)**  used to be common, but has [declined in post-war years: more so in the US than in the UK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=closing%20down%2Cshut%20up%20shop%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cshut%20up%20shop%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclosing%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshut%20up%20shop%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshut%20up%20shop%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

> **They are** closing.
>
> **They're** closing.

Both could either mean that the shop is closed for the night or that it is bankrupt. You'd have to look at the shop to be able to tell.

Answer (score 1):

They are closing the shop = closing for the day

The store is closing down = closing permanently.

Comment: That's a bit oversimplified. Moreover, one could say, "They are closing the shop" and have it mean closing permanently, particularly if context hinted in that direction: _They went into business two years ago, but they've never been able to make any money. It's a hard decision for them, but they are closing the shop._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second sentence (***They're closing their shop.***) could mean they're going out of business, but it's equally possible it means it's closed just for the day. Same with the first sentence.

But there's an idiom, used in American English only, that the other answers haven't mentioned, which is this:

> **They're closing *up* shop.**

This *usually* means the shop is going out of business.

> John: Have you been to Orange Julius lately?
>
> Mary: No, Orange Julius has **closed up shop**.
>
> John: I might cry.

With this idiom, you omit the possessive pronoun "there":

> Closed up shop  **[Correct]**
>
> Closed up their shop **[Not an idiom]**

### EDIT

Here are a few references that support what I'm saying:

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/close+up+shop

http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/close-up-shop

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close%20up%20shop

For what it's worth, I've noticed in all these references "closed forever" is mentioned first and "closed temporarily" is mentioned second.

Here's a reference to ***shut up shop***, supposedly a British idiom:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shut%20up%20shop

Comment: I've only ever heard this idiom "closing up shop" from American English speakers. On this side of the pond the usual idiom is "They're closing down".

Comment: @gburton - I've heard closing up shop here in the US, but I think it can mean closing for the day just as easily as closing for good. I think you're "closing down" might be a better option.

Comment: According to these NGrams, it is pretty uncommon in AmE https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=closing+down%2Cclosing+up+shop&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclosing%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclosing%20up%20shop%3B%2Cc0, and in BrE is is virtually non-existent https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=closing+down%2Cclosing+up+shop&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclosing%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclosing%20up%20shop%3B%2Cc0

Comment: OK, I think I made the bad assumption it was used in Britain, because none of the definitions I looked up said it was American-only and Britain uses "shop" more than "store." But I still think **close up shop** is fairly common in the U.S. That NGram is a little misleading, because **closing down** is much less specific than **closing up shop**. And it's more common to say it in simple past tense than continuous: https://tinyurl.com/y7mx8tra

Comment: Per comments, I've modified my answer to say it's American English only. But I stand by the other things I said.

Comment: "There" is not a possessive pronoun.